# Passing an Array of Pointers and Receiving Error Message

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Hi I'm trying to pass an array to pointers to a function. I tried doing it two ways. The first way I did was pass *array into the function but then I get the error message below. So I realized the mistake and changed it to array. But that made me think, why does the error say expecting a double pointer? The error now confuses me little bit. Could someone explain. Thanks.

```
add(struct node *arrayy[],int value)
{
struct node *nodey = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
nodey->x=value;

if(arrayy[value]==NULL)
{
printf("I am not pointing to something...now I am hehehe\n");
 arrayy[value]=nodey;
}
else
{
printf("I already have a head..now my link is pointing at something\n");
arrayy[value]->link=nodey;
}   
}

struct node *array[10]={NULL};
add(*array,4);
add(array,4);
```

Error Message

```
note: expected ‘struct node **’ but argument is of type ‘struct node *’
```

Comment: Which line does this? The second to last? It's probably because you are dereferencing the first element of the array of pointers.

Comment: add(*array,4) invokes the error message

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
struct node *array[10]={NULL};
```

which is of type `struct node *[]` (aka, `struct node **`).

This is the type that `add` expects.

If you dereference that (with `*array`), your types no longer match the prototype of `add`.

Comment: I just want to make sure why it's (aka, struct node **). Is it because  in my case I have an array of pointers. And arrays work by pointing to the first index of the array. So if I have something pointing to the first index of my array then It's a double pointer because the first index is already a pointer. Is this right?

Comment: @user68212 - The way I think of it is that an array 'points' to its contents.  So for a standard array, say `int thingy[]`, I have an `int *` which I can dereference using the special array notation, `thingy[2]`, to get an `int`.  In your case you have an array of pointers, so your array variable is a `struct node **`, and when you dereference it (to, eg, get contents) you get a `struct node *` (the type of its contents)